# Keeping precision of integers, passed as doubles

Tags: java, algorithm, floating-point, double, precision

I have a service which receives doubles from outer world. I know for sure that all doubles have only 4 digits after decimal point. *It is important to emphasize, that original system which sends data to me works with 5 digit integers, so all data "behind" these 5 digits is meaningless and misleading.* To keep precision I want to convert incoming doubles to integers, work with integers, and then convert them back to doubles to return back. I see that in theory, knowing that inputs always have 4 digits after decimal point I should not be losing precision here at all, taking into account that ***I only apply addition / subtraction*** to these numbers. ***No division and multiplication involved.***

i.e.

- A double like 1.2345 is received (I know that 1.23456789 cannot be received)
- I multiply it by 10,000 and convert to integer
- Now I can do exact integer calculations (addition and subtraction only) which means the result must be precise (opposed to addition and subtraction using doubles)
- Before returning, I divide my result by 10,000 again to convert back to double

Unfortunately I am already losing accuracy in the conversions. My following test code shows this:

```
double[] examples = {1.3456, 6.0000, 1.9999, 7.0001};
int[] inInt = new int[4];
double[] outDouble = new double[4];

// Input conversion from double to int
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    inInt[i] = (int) (examples[i] * 10_000);
}

// Integer calculations elided

// Output conversion back to double
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    outDouble[i] = ((double) inInt[i] / 10_000.0);
}

// Show
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(examples));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inInt));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(outDouble));
```

The above code gives me

```
[1.3456, 6.0, 1.9999, 7.0001]
[13455, 60000, 19999, 70001]
[1.3455, 6.0, 1.9999, 7.0001]
```

So you can see, while the 2nd to 4th example work, the `1.3456` lost precision when converting to int, as it became `13455` instead of `13456`.

Is it possible to eliminate precision losses here completely?

I see only one option: double > string > integer > operations with integers > construct string > build double, but it's quite laborious. I am using Java, but I don't think that's important here.

PS
By "precision loss" here I mean any loss of precision which results from double nature of incoming data, i.e. calculation "without precision loss" for me is calculation made on integers, which are built from incoming data.

Comment: Please describe exactly what you mean by "precision loss", what you are expecting and what is "not good" about what you're getting.

Comment: You say "I have a service which receives doubles from outer world".  Does it receive them as strings, or as doubles?  If it receives them as strings, then you want to (somehow) convert them to scaled integers *without* converting to `double` first.  But if it receives them as `double`, then you definitely need to round after multiplying, and RaffleBuffle's answer applies.

Comment: But the fundamental issue is that if you're actually receiving them as `double`, your statement "1.2345 comes to me, I know that 1.23456789 cannot come" is meaningless.  You'll never get 1.2345; instead you're going to actually get 1.234499999999 (and about 40 more nonzero digits after that).

Comment: *No division and multiplication involved...* **Except** for that multiplication by 10000.  No joke: that's your problem.

Comment: If you want accuracy rather than speed, use `BigDecimal` rather than `double`. Your service should return text which you parse as `BigDecimal`.

Comment: What is the largest any of the numbers can be?

Comment: @SteveSummit, 
Service receives data as doubles. 
I know that double representation is not showing all the digits after decimal point. Its probably better to say that rounding 1.234499999999 to 1.2345 works perfectly for me.
Multiplication by 10000 is something I have added to keep precision. I am trying to say that in a number which comes only first 5 digits are important for me. Nothing else matters. Thats why I want to x 10000 to make it integer and work without losing precision.

Comment: @EricPostpischil All numbers are doubles roughly in 0.5 - 1.5 zone.

Comment: @SteveSummit, one more explanation. In the system which sends data to me the values are stored as integers, so there is no sense to use any data "behind" 5th digit.

Comment: @Bohemian, here I refer to precision loss which results from double nature of incoming numbers. I want to avoid it. If I were doing this operations manually on the paper I would easily succeed:
take 1.2345, write 12345, do the needful, get result 15432, return 1.5432

Comment: If you are receiving only `double` values that are the `double` values nearest numbers in [0, 2) with four decimal digits after the decimal point, and you do only a few additions and subtractions with them, then you can get the desired results simply by rounding the final results with `Math.round(10000*x)/10000`. You can also get the desired results by converting each received value to an integer with `NewValue = Math.round(10000*OldValue)`, doing the arithmetic with integers, and producing the final values with `FinalValue = Result / 10000`.

Comment: Note that proper Stack Overflow procedure would be for you to edit the new information into the question, including the range of the values, a bound on the number of operations performed, and a correct description of the input. It is fundamentally impossible to receive a `double` value that is 1.2345 because 1.2345 is not representable in `double`. It is important to understand what numbers `double` can represent and how to describe the input correctly.

Comment: There are two or three ways of looking at this: (1) If the sending system keeps these numbers as fixed-point decimal, but sends them to you as binary floating point, *that* represents a certain, fundamental amount of information loss right there, which you will never get around as long as transmission is via floating point.  If the sending system is using fixed point, and if you desire to use fixed point also, you really ought to be using a scheme which transmits data between systems using fixed point.  (But I realize that changing the transmission format may not be an option for you.)

Comment: (2) The "information loss" involved in converting decimal fractions to binary is, up to a point, reversible.  (That's why Eric Postpischil was asking you about the range of your numbers.)  As long as you don't "run out of precision" while working with your data in the floating point realm, and if certain other conditions are met, you can perfectly recover your decimal fractions again at the end, without precision loss or noise, but doing this faithfully necessarily involves rounding (not simple truncation).

Comment: So, as long as you round after multiplying by 10000, you should be fine.  But based on what you've said, I believe you would be equally fine doing all your calculations using floating point, and rounding when printing or transmitting your final results.  That is, whatever "precision loss" it is that you're fighting, I do not believe that it's actually necessary to do all your work using integers in order to correct it.  But the arguments here do depend on the fact that, as you say, your manipulations of this data (after any initial multiplication) all involve simple additions and subtractions.

Answer (score 0):

Use reference `Double` instead of primitive `double` for your input and convert to `BigDecimal` for accuracy.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Double[] n  = {1.3456, 6.0000, 1.9999, 7.0001};
    int[] in    = new int[4];
    double[] od = new double[4];

    final BigDecimal tenK = BigDecimal.valueOf(10000);

    for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
        in[i] = BigDecimal.valueOf(n[i]).multiply(tenK).intValue();
    }

    for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
        od[i] = in[i] / tenK.doubleValue();
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(n)); 
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(in));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(od));
}
```

If the transformation is a recurring task, it can be extracted into a function:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Double[] n  = {1.3456, 6.0000, 1.9999, 7.0001};
    int[] in    = new int[4];
    double[] od = new double[4];

    final BigDecimal tenK = BigDecimal.valueOf(10000);

    final DoubleToIntFunction multiplyBYTenK = d -> BigDecimal.valueOf(d).multiply(tenK).intValue();
    final IntToDoubleFunction divideByTenK   = i -> i / tenK.doubleValue();

    Arrays.setAll(in, i -> multiplyBYTenK.applyAsInt(n[i]));
    Arrays.setAll(od, i -> divideByTenK.applyAsDouble(in[i]));

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(n)); //
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(in));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(od));
}
```

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer. How code works is important. What code does, in detail, is important. Concepts are important. Why the previous code did not work is important. Why the new code works is important.